# Algorithm : selecting points from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am facing a hard time to find the right algorithm for my problem.
I have two big lists(or sets) of numbers,list A and list B.list A have sorted real numbers
and list B have sorted real numbers,I want to create a list C that contain the selected points from list B, the selection from list B work in this way, from each element(number)in list A I must search for the nearest number( abs( A.element-B.element)=minimum ).
I will give some examples because its hard to explain.
example1:

```
A= [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B= [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.1, 19.76, 19.72, 19]

C= [20.1, 19.72, 19]
```

conditions:
list C can't have repetitive points, for example if two elements from list A share the same point from list B (because its are the nearest point for both of the point in list A)
then one of the points of list A must select the second nearest point from list B
example 2:

```
A= [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B= [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.3, 19.9, 19, 18]

C= [20.3, 19.9, 19]
# I it must not choose  C= [19.9, 19, 18] because its not an optimum solution
```

notes:
list B its always bigger than list A at least 4 times more, so if A have 10 elements B will have at least 40 elements

so let me re-explain it in fast way, list C must have sorted not repeated elements selected from list B , these points selected from list B must be the nearest possible to each element from list A.

I hope my explanation and my English was good enough :)
please help me to find a good way to do it in python 2.7
thanks all

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I did try a code to select directly the nearest points possible but that won't work because it fail in example 2

Comment: It seems that what you are trying to do is minimise `sum(abs(a - c) for a, c in zip(A, C))`; is that correct?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have to admit that I am still a beginner in python , so I don't have any idea what yours instruction (zip ???) do :) , sorry .

Comment: @jonrsharpe anyway I thinks its wrong because I want abs(a-b)=min and then store it in c.

Comment: I want to thanks every body for posting the solutions , I will try them tonight becacuse now I am not in home. thanks again

Comment: @user2776193 you can look `zip` up [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) - basically, that code combines the elements in `A` and `B` pairwise and calculates the sum of the differences between elements. Your problem is precisely because you are trying to minimise each pair `abs(a - b)` in turn, rather than minimising the sum over all pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple **dynamic programming solution**, 
The sub states are defined as dp[i][j] holds the value of the optimal assignment of elements of listA from 0 upto including i when we have the values of listB available from index 0 upto including index j.

Now for each element, there are two options, we either match listA[i] with listB[j] or we don't. So the dp relation is

> dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j-1] + abs(listA[i]-listB[j]),    dp[i][j-1]);

The **working Java code** implementing this dynamic programming solution in a top-down manner using memoization is shown [here](http://ideone.com/P0naEV).

```
public class Main {     
    static double[] a = {20.0, 19.6, 19.2};
    static double[] b = {22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.3, 19.9, 19, 18};  // declare the 2 arrays
    static boolean[][] takes; // tells about the dp state.
    static double INF = 1000.0;
    static double[][] dp;         // gives the answer for the above defined dp states

    public static void main(String[] args){
        dp = new double[a.length][b.length];
        takes = new boolean[a.length][b.length];

        for(int i=0; i<dp.length; i++)
            Arrays.fill(dp[i], Double.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(maxMatching(a.length-1, b.length-1));
        printSolution(a.length-1, b.length-1);
    }

    static void printSolution(int i, int j){
        if(i==-1 || j==-1)return;
        if(takes[i][j]){
            System.out.println(a[i] + " " + b[j]);
            printSolution(i-1, j-1);
        }else{
            printSolution(i, j-1);
        }
    }

    static double maxMatching(int i, int j){
        //if there are no numbers left to be matched
        if(i==-1)                        return 0;
        //If there are numbers to match but no number to which we can match
        if(j==-1)                        return INF;
        //If we have already solved this problem 
        if(dp[i][j] != Double.MAX_VALUE) return dp[i][j];

        double val1 = maxMatching(i, j-1); // ith number of listAis not matched with jth number of listB
        double val2 = Math.abs(a[i] - b[j]) + maxMatching(i-1, j-1);
        // When ith number is matched with the jth number

        // take the minimum of the above two.
        if(Double.compare(val1, val2)>0){
            dp[i][j] = val2;
            takes[i][j] = true;
        }else{
            dp[i][j] = val1;
        }
        return dp[i][j];
    }
}
```

Running Time analysis: The code works in `O(NM)` time where N is the length of list1 and M is the length of list2. This is follows from the fact that there are `O(NM)` subproblems and `O(1)` time is spent per subproblem.

Edit: This solution as opposed to the other two O(nlogn) solutions **will work on all test cases and always find the correct answer**. I dont think there even exists a guaranteed O(nlogn) solution that correctly solves all versions of the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, seems to be a great solution , but I don't know java .maybe I will ask my friend to convert it to python :)   . thanks again for the algorithm

Comment: ok even that I don't know java, but I compiled the code and did some tests and it did pass them all . so I will chose it as the right answer if that its not in python

Comment: could you please comment the code or explain the algorithm so I can convert it to python by my self, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect

def solve(A, B):

    A.reverse()
    B.reverse()
    C, indices = [], []

    for x in A:

        i = bisect.bisect_left(B, x)
        if i == 0:
            C.append(B[0])
            indices.append(0)
        elif i == len(B):
            C.append(B[-1])
            indices.append(len(B)-1)
        else:
            minn = min((i-1, i, i+1), key=lambda y:abs(x-B[y]))
            C.append(B[minn])
            indices.append(minn)
    seen = set()
    for i, x in enumerate(C):
        if x in seen:
            C[i] = B[indices[i]+1]
            seen.add(B[indices[i]+1])
        else:
            seen.add(x)

    C.reverse()
    return C

A= [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B= [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.1, 19.76, 19.72, 19]
assert solve(A, B) == [20.1, 19.72, 19]

A= [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B= [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.3, 19.9, 19, 18]
assert solve(A, B) == [20.3, 19.9, 19]

A = [20,17,14,11]
B = [22,21,20,19,18,17,16]
assert solve(A, B) == [20, 18, 17, 16]
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but your solution fails in some cases , for example:  'A = [20,17,14,11]
B = [22,21,20,19,18,17,16]'

Comment: it fail in this case :)  A = [20,17,13,11] B = [22,15,9,8,7,6,5,4,3]

Comment: @user2776193 What is the expected output for this one?

Comment: @user2776193 But 9 is the closest item to 11 not 8, 13 is closest to 15 not 9 and even the accepted answer fails for this.

Comment: yeah but there are no other acceptable solutions  , so its the nearest (better than nothing)

Answer (score 1):

using binary search

```
def binary(arr, val):
    assert len(arr) > 0
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return 0
    l2 = len(arr) // 2
    if abs(arr[l2-1] - val) > abs(arr[l2] - val):
        return l2 + binary(arr[l2:], val)
    else:
        return binary(arr[0:l2], val)

def closest_points(A, B):
    C = []
    for val in A:
        idx = binary(B, val)
        C.append(B[idx])
        B.pop(idx)
    return C

A = [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B = [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.1, 19.76, 19.72, 19]
A.reverse()
B.reverse()
C = closest_points(A, B)
C.reverse()
assert C == [20.1, 19.72, 19]

A = [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B = [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.3, 19.9, 19, 18]
A.reverse()
B.reverse()
C = closest_points(A, B)
C.reverse()
assert C == [20.3, 19.9, 19]
```

The complexity is len(A)*log(len(B))

---

In fact it does work with your examples, but it doesn't comply with your requirements (like other binary search based only proposed solution :( ) The propert way, without explosing the complexity is to use the [Iterative closest point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your help, your solution seems to be the best one , I tested with some cases and it did pass them. but you said that it will not work in all cases, could you give an example when it will fail ?  thanks

Comment: Because, I think it should work without the .reverse() statements. 
For the first example, if I remove the .reverse() statements, it still works.
For the second example, If I remove the .reverse() statements, it fails because it doesn't give the best pairing answer.
With .reverse():
A = [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
C = [20.3, 19.9, 19]
|| A - C || = 0.22

Without:
A = [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
C = [19.9, 19, 20.3]
|| A - C || = 1.58

Comment: ok, so the question now is , will it fail in some cases with the reverse ? , I tried to cover all the cases but still not sure that I coverd them all , and I am worry :(

Comment: @ticapix Can you please explain what logic you have used in your program? And please add a description as to why it should always work on all testcases.

Comment: @invin: I don't think it will work for all testcases.
If I understood correctly the problem description, we want to pair points from A and B to C in such a way that the *total* distance ||A - C|| is minimal.

My solution doesn't do that. It only pair points from A with the closest immediate points from B. It doesn't do any global optimization.

That's why I mentioned the Iterative Closest Point algorithm earlier.

Comment: @invin @ticapix  in fact , it fail in this case :(  `A = [20, 19, 13]
B = [21, 20, 14, 11, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

This can be thought of as a [linear programming assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) (or maximal bipartite matching problem) wherein you have to assign some sources to destinations with minimum cost possible.

```
List A is your list of sources.  
List B is your list of destinations.  
Since list B is larger, you have to create dummy sources in List A to make the problem balanced.
The cost of assigning element i from list A to element j of List B = abs(A[i] - B[j])
```

It can now be solved using the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) in almost O(n^3) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code that comes to my mind for it:

```
b := 0
For each element a in array A:
    while b < length(B) and a < B[b]:
        b++
    if b == length(B):
        Push B[-1] into C
    else if b == 0:
        Push B[0] into C
    else:
        if abs(B[b] - a) < abs(B[b - 1] - a):
            Push B[b]
        else:
            Push B[b - 1]
            b++
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
A = [20.0, 19.6, 19.2]
B = [22.454, 22.224, 21, 20.3, 19.9, 19, 18]
C = []

def lowDiff(var, B):
    prev, low = (0,0)
    for i in B:
        num = abs(i - var)
        if num < prev:
            low = i

        prev = num

    return low

for i in A:
    C.append(lowDiff(i, [x for x in B if x not in C])])

C.sort(reverse=True)
```